# How to inhibit mouse-controlled popup windows with Thesaurus

Tags: popup

I have bound C-x t to the command `thesaurus-choose-synonym-and-replace` (from the [`thesaurus` library](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/dpchiesa-elisp/blob/master/thesaurus.el)).  When I execute the command, I get a popup under Windows 11 like this:

[image]

I can pick items by pressing the first letter, but I would prefer not to have a Windows popup at all.  I would prefer, for example, that the menu appear in the minibuffer, since I work faster if I can use the keyboard and not have to use the mouse.  How might I accomplish this?

Comment: AFAICT, the only choices are `x-popup-menu` and `dropdown-list` (presumably only the latter is available on Windows). Do `C-h v thesaurus-prompt-mechanism` for more info.

Comment: I changed the value of {thesaurus-prompt-mechanism} from {x-popup-menu} to {dropdown-list}, but still get a Windows popup, not anything like a typical Emacs list.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this isn't vanilla Emacs (i.e., `emacs -Q`). It's not clear (to me) what library you're using for that command.

---

But if you are open to another library, maybe try [Synonyms](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Synonyms). Command `synonyms` prompts for a word (default: selected word or word under cursor) and lets you see/grab synonyms, with completion.

It doesn't automatically replace the selected word or word at point with any of the synonyms. But you easily could write a command to do that (or just copy and paste one).

Comment: I'll try this and see how it works for me.